# Navbar different href on toggle and logo

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to `href` a logo in a `navbar`. With this code the all `navbar` have the toggle `href` and I can't put a different `href` on the logo.

```
<h3 class="nav-toggle icon">
  <a href="#navigation">
    <?php _e( 'Navigation', 'woothemes' ); ?>
  </a>
  <a href="http://hobbymedia.net">
    <img src="http://hobbymedia.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/logo3-mobilex2.png" alt="" width="200" height="38" />
  </a>
</h3>
```

Comment: What............?

Comment: You have not close the last <a>

Comment: <h3 class="nav-toggle icon"><a href="#navigation"><?php _e( 'Navigation', 'woothemes' ); ?></a> <a href="http://website.net">
<img src="http://website.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/logo3-mobilex2.png" alt="" width="200" height="38" />
</a> </h3>

Comment: i close </a> </h3> but dosent work all the bar have the href of the  #navigation